# Using constant defined number of digits

Tags: c, constants, c-preprocessor, digits

I would like to use a constant defined number of digits

```
    #define DIGITS 10
    printf(%0DIGITSd \n, myvalue)
```

Will that work ? If not, how can I do it in a simple way ?

Comment: For better answers, define what to do if `myvalue` has fewer digits than `DIGITS`  (zero fill, space fill, on the left or right).  Define what is wanted if `myvalue` has more digits than `DIGITS`. (Print wider anyways, truncate left, truncate right, ****)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the string.

In C, a string is actually specified by a *sequence* of string literals. So you can do:

```
#define DIGITS "10"

printf( "%0" DIGITS "d\n", myvalue );
```

The preprocessor can also generate strings from other tokens (such as numbers). Check into the *stringize operator* (`#`), but I'd recommend only using it if you really need it.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot !

Ps: The missing quotes were on purpose. I had no idea on how to do this ^^

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the width as a parameter to `printf`:

```
 printf("%0*d \n", DIGITS, myvalue)
```

Comment: [Edit1] 

Thanks for your answer ! And what about sscanf ? Let's say I want to do this:

        sscanf(buff.data,"%06\n",&value);

with an constant defined number of digits. How may I pass the width to sscanf ?

Comment: @user3290274 It seems that `sscanf` uses `*` for different purpose. Only way is to use string literal trick, as in Potatoswatter's answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't work this way, macro names are not interpolated within string literals.

I think it's not possible to do it in C, unless you do `#define DIGITS "10"` or generate (parts of) your source file. Or try this hack if `DIGITS` is a decimal constant between 0 and 10:

```
#define DIGITS 10
#define STR_0 "0"
#define STR_1 "1"
#define STR_2 "2"
#define STR_3 "3"
#define STR_4 "4"
#define STR_5 "5"
#define STR_6 "6"
#define STR_7 "7"
#define STR_8 "8"
#define STR_9 "9"
#define STR_10 "10"
#define STR(i) STR_##i

...
  printf("%0" STR(DIGITS) "d\n", myvalue);
```